# Some icons in Xubuntu Panel are inverted / without color

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, xfce-panel

Out of sudden, some of the Panel icons don't have colors any more in Xubuntu 22.04:

Icons affected are:

- Bluetooth settings
- Dropbox
- Wifi

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been caused by this setting:

[image]

Changing it to "Adwaita" fixedit.